# How to get state from service fabric actor without waiting for other methods to complete?

Tags: c#, azure-service-fabric

I have a service running that is iterating over X actors asking them for their state using the ActorProxy.

Its important to me that this service is not blocked waiting for some other long running method in the actor from ect reminder callbacks.

Is there some way to call the below simple example GetState() that would allow the method to complete right way without blocking incase of some reminder running.

```
class Actor : IMyActor{

public Task<MyState> GetState() => StateManager.GetAsync("key")
}
```

alterntive.

what is the proper way form the service to call and if it dont reply within 5 sec, just containue.

```
var proxy = ActorProxy.Create<IMyActor();
var state = await proxy.GetState(); // this will wait until the actor is ready to send back the state.
```

Comment: Don't perform long running actions on the actor -- it should be able to respond immediately. -- If you need a long running action, spin it off onto a child actor that notifies the parent when it's done. -- That way the parent actor can stay responsive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to read the actor state even for Actors that are currently executing a blocking method. Actors store their state using an [`IActorStateManager`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicefabric.actors.runtime.iactorstatemanager) which in turn uses an [`IActorStateProvider`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicefabric.actors.runtime.iactorstateprovider). The [`IActorStateProvider`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicefabric.actors.runtime.iactorstateprovider) is instantiated once per [`ActorService`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicefabric.actors.runtime.actorservice). Each partition instantiates the [`ActorService`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicefabric.actors.runtime.actorservice) that is responsible for hosting and running actors. The actor service is at the core a `StatefulService` (or rather [`StatefulServiceBase`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicefabric.services.runtime.statefulservicebase) which is the base class that regular stateful service uses). With this in mind, we can work with the `ActorService` that caters to our Actors the same way we would work with a regular service, i.e. with a service interface based on [`IService`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicefabric.services.remoting.iservice).

The [`IActorStateProvider`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicefabric.actors.runtime.iactorstateprovider) (Implemented by [`KvsActorStateProvider`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicefabric.actors.runtime.kvsactorstateprovider) if you are using Persisted state) has two methods that we can use:

```
Task<T> LoadStateAsync<T>(ActorId actorId, string stateName, CancellationToken cancellationToken = null);
Task<PagedResult<ActorId>> GetActorsAsync(int numItemsToReturn, ContinuationToken continuationToken, CancellationToken cancellationToken);
```

Calls to these methods are not affected by actors' locks, which makes sense since these are designed to support all actors on a partition.

**Example:**

Create a custom `ActorService` and use that one to host your actors:

```cs
public interface IManyfoldActorService : IService
{
    Task<IDictionary<long, int>> GetCountsAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken);
}

public class ManyfoldActorService : ActorService, IManyfoldActorService
{
    ...
}
```

Register the new ActorService in `Program.Main`:

```cs
ActorRuntime.RegisterActorAsync<ManyfoldActor>(
    (context, actorType) => new ManyfoldActorService(context, actorType)).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

Assuming we have a simple Actor with the following method:

```cs
    Task IManyfoldActor.SetCountAsync(int count, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30), cancellationToken).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        var task = this.StateManager.SetStateAsync("count", count, cancellationToken);
        ActorEventSource.Current.ActorMessage(this, $"Finished set {count} on {this.Id.GetLongId()}");
        return task;
    }
```

It waits for 30 seconds (to simulate long running, blocking, method calls) and then set a state value `"count"` to an `int`.

In a separate service we can now call the `SetCountAsync` for the Actors to generate some state data:

```cs
    protected override async Task RunAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var actorProxyFactory = new ActorProxyFactory();
        long iterations = 0;
        while (true)
        {
            cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            iterations += 1;
            var actorId = iterations % 10;
            var count = Environment.TickCount % 100;
            var manyfoldActor = actorProxyFactory.CreateActorProxy<IManyfoldActor>(new ActorId(actorId));
            manyfoldActor.SetCountAsync(count, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
            ServiceEventSource.Current.ServiceMessage(this.Context, $"Set count {count} on {actorId} @ {iterations}");
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3), cancellationToken);
        }
    }
```

This method simply loops endlessly changing the values of the actors. (Note the correlation between total of 10 actors, delay for 3 second and the 30 second delay in actor. Simply designed this way to prevent an infinite buildup of Actor calls waiting for a lock). Each call is also executed as fire-and-forget so we can continue on to updating the state of the next actor before that one returns. Its a silly piece of code, it is just designed this way to prove the theory.

Now in the actor service we can implement the method `GetCountsAsync` like this:

```cs
    public async Task<IDictionary<long, int>> GetCountsAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        ContinuationToken continuationToken = null;
        var actors = new Dictionary<long, int>();

        do
        {
            var page = await this.StateProvider.GetActorsAsync(100, continuationToken, cancellationToken);

            foreach (var actor in page.Items)
            {
                var count = await this.StateProvider.LoadStateAsync<int>(actor, "count", cancellationToken);
                actors.Add(actor.GetLongId(), count);
            }

            continuationToken = page.ContinuationToken;
        }
        while (continuationToken != null);

        return actors;
    }
```

This uses the underlying `ActorStateProvider` to query for all known Actors (for that partition) and then directly reads the state for each this way 'bypassing' the Actor and not being blocked by the actor's method execution.

Final piece, some method that can call our ActorService and call `GetCountsAsync` across all partitions:

```cs
    public IDictionary<long, int> Get()
    {
        var applicationName = FabricRuntime.GetActivationContext().ApplicationName;
        var actorServiceName = $"{typeof(IManyfoldActorService).Name.Substring(1)}";
        var actorServiceUri = new Uri($"{applicationName}/{actorServiceName}");

        var fabricClient = new FabricClient();
        var partitions = new List<long>();
        var servicePartitionList = fabricClient.QueryManager.GetPartitionListAsync(actorServiceUri).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        foreach (var servicePartition in servicePartitionList)
        {
            var partitionInformation = servicePartition.PartitionInformation as Int64RangePartitionInformation;
            partitions.Add(partitionInformation.LowKey);
        }

        var serviceProxyFactory = new ServiceProxyFactory();

        var actors = new Dictionary<long, int>();
        foreach (var partition in partitions)
        {
            var actorService = serviceProxyFactory.CreateServiceProxy<IManyfoldActorService>(actorServiceUri, new ServicePartitionKey(partition));

            var counts = actorService.GetCountsAsync(CancellationToken.None).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            foreach (var count in counts)
            {
                actors.Add(count.Key, count.Value);
            }
        }
        return actors;
    }
```

Running this code will now give us 10 actors that every 33:d second gets it's state updated and where each actor is busy for 30 seconds each time. The Actor service sees the updated state as soon as each actor method returns.

There are some things omitted in this sample, for instance, when you load the state in the actor service we should probably guard against timeouts.

Comment: Awesome answer :)

Comment: yoape - i used this approach and fist noticed somethign odd now. When using the stateprovider on the actorservice to update some state for an actor. Then a actor already activated doing loadstate, it get the old value not the new updated value. Is this something you seen also?

Comment: @PoulK.Sørensen, we are still using this approach in production code. We haven't seen that behaviour there (yet), seems to be working for us. Which version of the SDK are you running?

Comment: this specific one 2.7.198 - will verify on a different project using latest also soon. I solved this by having the actors report to the actor service when they are deactivating. Then if the actor service see that new state is avaible it will activate the actor again after deactivation and then the actor has the latest state.  So the problem i was seeing is that state updated from the actor service is not updated in already active actors. (Maybe its something with state being in memory and actor service is manipulating state on disk)

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this. Actors are single-threaded. If they are doing long running work that they are waiting to complete inside any actor method, then any other method including those from outside will have to wait.

Comment: Did we not have some ReadOnly attributes in earlier sdk versions? Is there any way to get the statemanager for a given actor then to look up the state without having to wait. I am convinced there must be a solution to what I want?

Comment: Readonly did exist in earlier releases but it was a hint about whether state needed to be replicated after the method exited and had no impact on single threaded locking semantics.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all the help. Was able to take your example and get it to work with a few tweaks. Only problem I had  was that I was  getting unknown type when passing Data Back to original Application Service.  Was getting

"ArrayOfKeyValueOflonglong is not expected. Add any types not known statically to the list of known types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding them to the list of known types passed to DataContractSerializer"

So I changed my Return type of GetCountsAsync to List <T> and inside my class I used the DataContract and DataMember class attribute and it worked fine.  Seems like the ability to retrieve state data from  many actors in Partitions  should be a core part of the Actor Service and you should not have to create a Custom Actor service to get the StateProvider information.  Once again , thank you!

Comment: Could you edit your answer to include your code, rather than just describing it?