# Service Fabric long running process

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I have a Web Api stateless service that is creating an Actor that does some long running processing via a reminder (fire and forget). It stores its own progress in local state. I am unable to get the progress of that long running process due to the single threaded nature of the Actor, any call to the method that gets the progress will wait until the long running process has completed. Does anyone have a solution for this (without using an external data source)?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42170652/how-to-get-state-from-service-fabric-actor-without-waiting-for-other-methods-to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simply wish to get the current state of your Actor without having to wait for an Actor lock you can actually use the underlying ActorService that is hosting the Actors to query the state without interrupting, or being blocked by the long running Actor method.

The ActorService hosting Actors is really just a StatelessService (with some bells and whistles) and you can communicate with it the same way you would communicate with any Service - add an [`IService`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicefabric.services.remoting.iservice) interface to it and the use [`IServiceProxy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicefabric.services.remoting.client.iserviceproxy) to talk to it. This SO Answer shows how you can do that [How to get state from service fabric actor without waiting for other methods to complete?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42170652/how-to-get-state-from-service-fabric-actor-without-waiting-for-other-methods-to/42180057#42180057)

If you want to get progress along the way even during the execution of your Actor method you can force a save of the state changes in the middle of your long running exectuion by calling [SaveStateAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicefabric.actors.runtime.iactorstatemanager#Microsoft_ServiceFabric_Actors_Runtime_IActorStateManager_SaveStateAsync_System_Threading_CancellationToken_)

Answer (score 1):

You could create a `ProgressTrackingActor` and periodically update it from the existing `Actor`. Query the `ProgressTrackingActor` for progress.

You can use an `ActorReference` to indicate which `Actor` to query progress for, or use the same ActorId value.